# What causes the "git rainbow"?

Tags: git, version-control

Sometimes when working with other developers with git version control I run into a problem where the git graph suddenly spawns countless parallels lines like in this image.

[image]
Image from [here](https://twitter.com/HenryHoffman/status/694184106440200192).

I have no idea what actions cause this and how to prevent this issue.

Usually this happens with just a couple of branches like master, staging and a few feature branches.

Comment: Are there many feature branches which are not re-integrated?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is not a bug since I have seen this phenomenon several times in different projects and different git clients. If you google [git rainbow](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+rainbow&tbm=isch) you will see that many other people have run into this issue too.

Comment: Looks to me like you have many branches that started at the same point, but you kept committing on them after they were merged, so they stick around

Comment: Look at the pink line, 5th from the left at the top and 4th from the left at the bottom. A bunch of other lines merge into the pink line. I bet that someone had a long lived branch and kept merging `master` into it (though, then you'd expect to see master alongside that branch). Or merged a bunch of other really old branches into it.

Comment: It looks like you have merges from many old points in the history. A line has to be drawn from the merge back the point where the thing being merged, and if that's a long time, the line has to sit alongside all the other lines for a long time

Answer (score 8):

This can occur when you create many branches, but do not continually merge master into them, and then never delete them once they are no longer used.

Before merging a topic branch in to master make sure you have merged master into the topic branch. Once the topic branch has been merged in to master, delete the topic branch.

This is one more reason why topic branches should be short lived.

Comment: I am a strong proponent of rebasing topic branches on master rather than merging master into them, precisely to keep history leaner.

Comment: @blue: Yes, that is definitely a good strategy, provided you know what you are doing. New git users should not rebase until they get a little more comfortable. A `git merge --squash` can also keep history cleaner, however squashed merges will not fix the rainbow. The rainbow is caused by too many branches diverging from master. At least a rebased branch will still show up, but not create additional layers in the graph.

Comment: Actually, many branches is not the only way you can get a git rainbow. It happened to me with only one branch + master, as I kept merging master into it. I just tried to replicate the situation artificially and failed.

Comment: It *can*, but I don't think this is a common cause of Git rainbows

Answer (score 2):

I think this just happens when there are a lot of parallell histories.

One way to avoid it is to enforce [“semi-linear
merges”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63621528/1725151). Basically you
demand that every PR is integrated into the main branch by (1) rebasing
on the main branch and then (2) doing a no-fast-forward merge. Thus, if
all feature branches are straight lines, your history will look like
this:

```
* Merge in feature-454 (main)
|\
| * Update docs (feature-456)
| |
| * Implement functionality
| |
| * Preliminary work
|/
* Merge in feature-8792
|\
| * Implement doorknob breaker (feature-8792)
|/
* Merge in feature-162
|\
[snip]
```

(I couldn’t be bothered to color them)

Assuming one eternal branch, there is always at most one
side-development since each feature branch has to rebase on top of the
main branch whenever it gets updated.

But do you want to do this? Unclear. This “rainbow” can be problematic,
but there may be cons to this “semi-linear merge” strategy as well:

1. Rebasing proven and tested commits on the upstream branch might give
   you effectively untested commits
2. In a very active codebase, this *catchup* activity might be hectic at
   times, and in a *very* active codebase it might be practically
   impossible without centralized coordination

Your mileage might vary. I haven’t tried this approach.

Comment: I find these to be particularly fantastic because they free you from the 'every commit needs to be green' constraint (I'm a big proponent of splitting up into smaller commits, even test-failing ones, when changes are large/complex enough, such as a complex refactor that must be completed all-or-nothing to be correct). Every _merge commit_ on master is green, but it can be merging branches composed of multiple commits. Rollbacks work nicely too: roll back any merge commit to any other, and you can be sure you're not rolling back to a non-green commit.

Comment: @Alexander Personally I agree that well-tested code is much more important on the mainline (`git log --first-parent`) than on side-branches. Well-tested code on side-branches are a nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

Each line is a branch. What you refer to as a "rainbow" is merely git displaying branches normally. Probably your real concern is not the colorfulness of the lines, but their number.

You can solve it by simply reducing the branch number. Branches may be deleted or merged. From that point on the graph will thin out.

Note that you can delete branches locally without losing them - they can still be fetched from the remote.

However, one wonders, what's even the point of maintaining so many branches? Are there really this many variants of your software that you keep track of? Probably not.